# An element with the same key but a different value already exists when using Roslyn with dotnet core

Tags: .net-core, roslyn

I updated a Roslyn parser project to dotnet core 3.1 and when Roslyn tries to open a solution for parsing using the following code:

```
 var properties = new Dictionary<string, string> { ["DesignTimeBuild"] = "true" };
 var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create(properties);
 Solution solution = workspace.OpenSolutionAsync(Solution).Result;
```

Will results in the following error:

> InnerException = {"An element with the same key but a different value
>   already exists. Key: DesignTimeBuild"}

It works to parse the same solution in the .Net version of the Roslyn parser project but dotnet core failes. Does Roslyn not support .net Core? I found this thread
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/28870

Any ideas about the current status of Roslyn or how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using the Buildalyzer:
https://github.com/daveaglick/Buildalyzer/blob/master/README.md#roslyn-workspaces